# How to relabel rows in a pandas Dataframe with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, r, pandas

I am planning to access all entries under a certain column, and search for string patterns.

An example of data entries in the pandas DataFrame are:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=kitty+pictures
https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylc=X3oDMTFiN25laTRvBF9TAzIwMjM1MzgwNzUEaXRjAzEEc2VjA3NyY2hfcWEEc2xrA3NyY2h3ZWI-?p=kitty+pictures&fr=yfp-t-694
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kitty+pictures
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=cat+pictures
```

I would like to use regular expressions to find the web search engine, and replace it with one word. So, you use regex to find `google` and replace all URLs above with `google`.

Normally, one would try

```
import re
string_example = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=cat+pictures"
re.search(r'google', string_example)
```

However, this only returns google, and does not replace it.

(1) How can I search the entire column entries within this DataFrame for `r'google` and then replace that URL with "Google"?

(2) How do you search only the column entries? I cannot pass in a string each time.

Comment: IIUC then `df.loc[df['url'].str.contains('google'), 'url'] = 'google'` should work

Comment: @EdChum Of course! I'm a fool. What about "string contains google AND cats"? Or "string contains google AND NOT cats"? That is, how do you search for multiple words?

Comment: `df.loc[df['url'].str.contains('google|cats'), 'url'] = 'google'`, `df.loc[(df['url'].str.contains('google')) & (~df['url'].str.contains('cat'), 'url'] = 'google'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to handle your various methods to generate the boolean mask to pass `loc` and set those rows:

```
In [126]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'url':['google', 'cat', 'google cat', 'dog']})
df

Out[126]:
          url
0      google
1         cat
2  google cat
3         dog

In [127]:    
df['url'].str.contains('google')

Out[127]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: url, dtype: bool

In [128]:    
df['url'].str.contains('google|cat')

Out[128]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: url, dtype: bool

In [129]:
(df['url'].str.contains('google')) & (~df['url'].str.contains('cat'))

Out[129]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: url, dtype: bool
```

you can then pass these conditions to loc:

```
In [130]:
df.loc[df['url'].str.contains('google'), 'url'] = 'yahoo'
df

Out[130]:
     url
0  yahoo
1    cat
2  yahoo
3    dog
```

Comment: One last question: How about "if it does not contain Google And does not contain cat, drop the row entry"?  I'm not sure how the negation tilde `~` would work in this case.

Comment: that would just be `~df['url'].str.contains('google|cat')`

Comment: I'm getting the hang of this now. Thanks for patience with a n00b!